# How to prevent images from being pixelated in chrome using css or anything else

Tags: css, reactjs, image, google-chrome, image-rendering

I'm developing a react website. In my Google Chrome browser, images showing as pixelated (image-rendering: pixelated) but in firefox work as expected (image-rendering: auto).
Here is the difference,

{images[0].preview} return an image url from an object

```
<img src={images[0].preview} className='border w-[250px] z-10 h-[85%] -mr-8 object-cover object-top shadow-portfolio' alt='' />
```

Here is css code for keeping image rendering same as firefox.

```
img { image-rendering: auto !important }
```

[Firefox Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izsrk.jpg)

[Chrome Image Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUWss.png)

How to show images in chrome like firefox ? I used (image-rendering: auto) for img tag but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution. If image mimetype is svg+xml then it will look perfect in chrome & firefox.